# SQL 2008R2: What's the fastest way to do a 'INSERT INTO target <all columns except two> SELECT <all columns> FROM source'

Tags: t-sql

I'm doing a SQL-to-SQL conversion, and have 50+ tables to convert from old (source) to new (target) database.   I think the answer is 'there's no really fast way to do this', but I'll ask the question anyways.

Each 'group' has..
Two Source tables:  Anywhere from 10 to 700 columns.
   These two tables have the same schema, although some columns have different collations. 
Target tables:  Number of columns = Columns in source tables + 2, as I added start_dt and end_dt.

I can't do a 'INSERT INTO Target SELECT * FROM Source' because of the two extra columns.

**Question:  What's the fastest way to do a 'INSERT INTO target  SELECT  FROM source'**

Using a view in the designer I don't see a way to select all and have it show all columns, and then just remove the two I don't need.  * displays as * instead of all column names.

I'll entertain third party apps on this one.

Thanks.
Jim

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server Management studio, expand your table.  You will see a couple nodes appear below the table name.  Columns, Keys, Constraints, etc...  Drag the "Column" node in to a query window and all of the columns will be added to the query window.  Tack on your 2 extra columns and execute it.

This is still somewhat manual, but it will save you a ton of typing.

Comment: easy, especially for a 1 time operation, even though you neglected to mention any punitive action(s) against whoever added that many columns to a table in the first place ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Always try to stay away from SELECT *. In SSMS right click on the table/view -> script as -> select. (The wording may not be exact. I am working from memory.) Then you don't have to type out all the fields.

If you mean the speed of getting the data over.

If you can on the destination:

- turn off all triggers
- drop indexes
- change the recovery of the DB to
  [bulk logged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173529%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)
- Do the inserts in batches

What about using SSIS?
How many records are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS-SQL-Server/Q_28574379.html).

```
DECLARE @source_table sysname
DECLARE @target_table sysname
DECLARE @col_list varchar(max)
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

--naturally replaced by cursor table loop in final code
SET @source_table = 'dbs'
SET @target_table = 'dbs'

SELECT @col_list = STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + src.name
    FROM sys.columns src
    INNER JOIN sys.columns trg ON
        trg.name = src.name
    WHERE
        src.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@source_table) AND
        trg.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@target_table)
    ORDER BY src.column_id
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, '')

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @target_table + ' ( ' + @col_list + ' ) SELECT ' + @col_list + ' FROM ' + @source_table + ' '
EXEC (@sql) 

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @target_table + ' ( ' + @col_list + ' ) SELECT ' + @col_list + ' FROM ' + @source_table + '_History '
EXEC (@sql)
```